# Error in apt-get update

Tags: apt

I have been getting following error while running 
`sudo apt-get update`

```
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Also sometimes I get a red icon in the Task Bar pane.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501372/intel-graphis-card-not-updating-problem-with-ppa

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the GPG key for that repository

Run the followings:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A902DDA375E52366

sudo apt-get update
```