# Intel Graphis card not updating. Problem with ppa?

Tags: drivers, apt, updates, update-manager, ppa

I'm trying to update my graphics card. Info:

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

I tried doing this in two ways:

1 . Command Line:

First add repository:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
```

Second, update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This updates everything, then eventually I get a problem:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

2 . Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux:

I downloaded it from [this site](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads)

Then ran the program, and let it do it's thing. Eventually I got this error:

```
W:GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Both error look the same, but I don't quite understand it.

How do I upgrade my graphics card driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first get rid of the ppa as it's not needed and that's what's causing your problems

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/glasen-intel-driver-saucy.list
```

To securely add the keys execute these commands

```
GET https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg | gpg --import
gpg --check-sigs --fingerprint 75E52366
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 7CB0FA13
gpg -a --export 75E52366 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Repeat for second key

```
GET https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 | gpg --import
gpg --check-sigs --fingerprint 2F4AAA66
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 144BD458
gpg -a --export 2F4AAA66 | sudo apt-key add -
```

more info on adding keys can be found here http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch7.en.html#s-deb-pack-sign

---

now execute these commands to add intel download installer for 14.04 64 bit

```
cd && wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.5-0intel1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.5-0intel1_amd64.deb
```

Now to run intel graphics installer run the following command in an open terminal

```
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Follow the instructions provided by the intel installer GUI. Save any unsaved work you may have and reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I already have the installer, but it didn't work completely. When I put your second code in, then updated, I got this: "W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366". Nevertheless, your first command line solved my problem :)

Comment: @user3259540 I updated the instructions to add the key. run sudo apt-get update when you finish.

Comment: @user3259540 that doesn't fix your problem unless you run the intel-linux-graphics-installer as you still aren't updated. `apt-get update` only updates the package list to perform **actual** updates you need to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: I thought that the reason intel-linux-graphics-installer didn't work was because when it checked the repositories, it got an error and stopped the whole process. Since I took it out with you first command, I think it worked. I _did_ run intel-linux-graphics-installer.. The process completed, and I got results.

Comment: I'm thankful for your instructions, but my understanding is that most of it (except the first line) is concerned with installing the intel-linux-graphics-installer, and then running it. If so, I already had it installed, but it wasn't working. Thanks for the instructions anyways.

Comment: @user3259540 okay, as long as you ran the installer and it worked you're good. Just wanted to make sure. It returned an error for a GPG key also and so I thought reinstalling might fix that but if it worked when you ran it your good.

Comment: @mchid - could you possibly add instructions for the `i386` architecture? Other questions like this have been turning up....

Answer (score 3):

To download properly from 01.org you need to import their GPG keys, as mentioned in the [release and installation notes](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux).  You may also want to disable the glasen ppa unless you intend to keep trying that source.

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -

wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: @mchid - the first line in the reported error list is "W:GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures coul..." indicating that the public keys are not available.

Comment: aah yes, I see that now, I've just never had to add the key and thought those were the instructions for the fedora (rpm) version as they install with the deb.